# Flask SQL Alchemy self join

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, self-join

I want to perform self join with the use of Flask SQL Alchemy. I have following table in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE table0 (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    property_0 TEXT,
    property_1 TEXT);


insert into table0(property_0, property_1) values('aa', 'bb');
insert into table0(property_0, property_1) values('cc', 'dd');
insert into table0(property_0, property_1) values('aa', 'ee');
insert into table0(property_0, property_1) values('bb', 'ee');
insert into table0(property_0, property_1) values('bb', 'rwqe');
insert into table0(property_0, property_1) values('aa', 'value_for_t00');
insert into table0(property_0, property_1) values('bb', 'value_for_t00');
insert into table0(property_0, property_1) values('aa', 'value_for_t01');
insert into table0(property_0, property_1) values('bb', 'value_for_t01');
```

and following query:

```sql
select t00.property_0 as t00_property_0, t01.property_0 as t01_property_0, t00.property_1 as t00_property_1, t01.property_1 as t01_property_1
from table0 t00
left join table0 t01 on t00.property_0 = t01.property_0 and t00.property_1 = 'value_for_t00' and t01.property_1 = 'value_for_t01';
```

which gives me the expected correct output:

```
 t00_property_0 | t01_property_0 | t00_property_1 | t01_property_1
----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------
 aa             |                | bb             |
 cc             |                | dd             |
 aa             |                | ee             |
 bb             |                | ee             |
 bb             |                | rwqe           |
 aa             | aa             | value_for_t00  | value_for_t01
 bb             | bb             | value_for_t00  | value_for_t01
 aa             |                | value_for_t01  |
 bb             |                | value_for_t01  |
(9 rows)
```

Basically in the table there are values in two rows which I would like to have in the one output row like in the following two:

```
 aa             | aa             | value_for_t00  | value_for_t01
 bb             | bb             | value_for_t00  | value_for_t01
```

but I want also to preserve the rest of rows with empty values.

In the Flask application I have following data model:

```py
class Table0(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'table0'

    id        = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    property_0 = db.Column(db.String)
    property_1 = db.Column(db.String)
    

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Relation(id='%s', property_0='%s', property_1='%s)>" % (self.id, self.property_0, self.property_1)
```

and following query:

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import pprint

db = SQLAlchemy()

t00 = db.aliased(Table0)
t01 = db.aliased(Table0)

on = (t00.property_0==t01.property_0) and \
     (t00.property_1=='value_for_t00') and \
     (t01.property_1=='value_for_t01')

result = db.session.query(t00)\
                    .join(t01, on, isouter=True)\
                    .with_entities(t00.property_0.label("t00_property_0"),
                                    t01.property_0.label("t01_property_0"),
                                    t00.property_1.label("t00_property_1"),
                                    t01.property_1.label("t01_property_1"))\
                    .all()
    
pprint.pprint(result)
```

Which I supposed was the query that corresponds to the query used in PostgreSQL, but for some reason it gives me different (and wrong) result:

```
[('aa', 'aa', 'bb', 'value_for_t01'),
 ('aa', 'aa', 'bb', 'value_for_t00'),
 ('aa', 'aa', 'bb', 'ee'),
 ('aa', 'aa', 'bb', 'bb'),
 ('cc', 'cc', 'dd', 'dd'),
 ('aa', 'aa', 'ee', 'value_for_t01'),
 ('aa', 'aa', 'ee', 'value_for_t00'),
 ('aa', 'aa', 'ee', 'ee'),
 ('aa', 'aa', 'ee', 'bb'),
 ('bb', 'bb', 'ee', 'value_for_t01'),
 ('bb', 'bb', 'ee', 'value_for_t00'),
 ('bb', 'bb', 'ee', 'rwqe'),
 ('bb', 'bb', 'ee', 'ee'),
 ('bb', 'bb', 'rwqe', 'value_for_t01'),
 ('bb', 'bb', 'rwqe', 'value_for_t00'),
 ('bb', 'bb', 'rwqe', 'rwqe'),
 ('bb', 'bb', 'rwqe', 'ee'),
 ('aa', 'aa', 'value_for_t00', 'value_for_t01'),
 ('aa', 'aa', 'value_for_t00', 'value_for_t00'),
 ('aa', 'aa', 'value_for_t00', 'ee'),
 ('aa', 'aa', 'value_for_t00', 'bb'),
 ('bb', 'bb', 'value_for_t00', 'value_for_t01'),
 ('bb', 'bb', 'value_for_t00', 'value_for_t00'),
 ('bb', 'bb', 'value_for_t00', 'rwqe'),
 ('bb', 'bb', 'value_for_t00', 'ee'),
 ('aa', 'aa', 'value_for_t01', 'value_for_t01'),
 ('aa', 'aa', 'value_for_t01', 'value_for_t00'),
 ('aa', 'aa', 'value_for_t01', 'ee'),
 ('aa', 'aa', 'value_for_t01', 'bb'),
 ('bb', 'bb', 'value_for_t01', 'value_for_t01'),
 ('bb', 'bb', 'value_for_t01', 'value_for_t00'),
 ('bb', 'bb', 'value_for_t01', 'rwqe'),
 ('bb', 'bb', 'value_for_t01', 'ee')]
```

Why the results are not the same and how to correct this?